# How to fix react is not a function discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been struggling with this issue for quite a while, so I want to make my bot react with the  emoji when someone reacts with  on the same message. However, I'm getting this error whenever I react with . Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'react' of undefined`

Any kind of help is really appreciated, thanks.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction,user) => {
     if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            const msg = reaction.message.channel.id
            await msg.react('')
        }   else if(reaction.emoji.name === ''){
                const channelId = reaction.message.channel.id;
                if (channelId){
                    channelId.delete();
                    
                }
            } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `msg` to the message's ID (which is a string), not to the message object. Replace the assignment with this one:

```js
const msg = reaction.message;
```